# Flux through the positive part of a sphere centered at $(0,0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Let $$B=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2<4, \ z\geq 0\}$$ and consider the vector field $$F:(x,y,z)\mapsto(x^3,y^3,z)$$

> I want to compute the flux of $F$ through $\partial B.$

We have $$\text{Div}F=3x^2+3y^2+1$$ and so by the divergence theorem we could compute the flux as $$\int_B 3x^2+3y^2+1 \ dx dy dz$$
but this triple integral does not look very friendly to me using spherical coordinates, because the sphere is centered in $(0,0,1).$

Another approach is by computing $$\partial B =\{x^2+y^2\leq 3, \ z=0\}\cup\{x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=4,  \ z>0\}$$

I can parametrize $\{x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=4,  \ z>0\}$ as $$x=2\sin \phi \cos \psi$$ $$y=2  \sin \phi \sin \psi$$ $$z= 2 \cos \phi +1$$ $$\phi\in[0,\pi], \psi \in [0,2 \pi)$$ but it does not seem to make calculations easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use a change of variables, then use spherical coordinates. Starting with

$$\int_B\left(3x^2+3y^2+1\right)dx\ dy\ dz$$

we let $u=x$, $v=y$, and $w=z-1$. Let's call our new volume of integration $C$; with the new variables, $C$ is the sphere centred at the origin with radius 2:

$$C=\{(u, v, w) : u^2+v^2+w^2<4, w>-1\}$$

Noting that the Jacobian determinant for this is just 1, we get that the flux is equivalently stated as

$$\int_C\left(3u^2+3v^2+1\right)du\ dv\ dw$$

From here, you can use either spherical or cylindrical coordinates to finish the computation, and it should be a lot more pleasant this time.

Comment: thanks. How would you do with the other approach? is it doable?

Comment: @ggeolier sorry, which other approach are you referring to? :0

Comment: The one where I do not use the divergence theorem but rather calculate the flux $\int_{\partial B}\langle F,N \rangle $ directly.

Comment: @ggeolier yeah, you’d start off the same way with the change of variables, then convert to spherical coordinates and calculate